# Adjust E-step on Ender 3 v2 Neo

Tags: print-quality, extruder, diy-3d-printer

I have just calibrated my extruder and everything is ok. When I extrude 100 mm of filament, everything is correct, but when I attach the Bowden tube to the nozzle, the length of filament that is extruded is not correct - it is much shorter. Is that normal?

The nozzle is almost new. It was working for only a few hours. How can I fix it? Do I need a new nozzle, or there is some another issue?
I tried some prints and they were just fine. Before calibration, they were terrible.

The method that I used to calibrate is described here, [Stupid Fast Way To Calibrate E Steps On Ender 3 (V2/Pro)](https://makershop.co/how-to-calibrate-esteps-ender-3/), calibrated with and without the Bowden tube - on the another end before nozzle. But when I attach the Bowden tube and extrude, the nozzle is all wrong.

I used the method from the link above. My prints were terrible before calibration. Using this method now my prints are ok. Method is without Bowden tube, printer extrude in the air. But when I extrude from nozzle distance in much shorter. Is that normal? Or is the method used to calibrate correct and enough?

Comment: I just edited this paragraph. Will try to attach picture tomorrow

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Yes, adding a picture will be great. Thanks again. :-)

Answer (score 1):

That calibration test shouldn't be used. You calibrate the extruder at zero load, it is far better to include the Bowden tube and the hot nozzle as these give pressure/resistance to the path. This may result in slightly different values for your steps.

Answer (score 0):

I am completely new to 3D printing so I followed this calibration with my new Ender 3 v2 NEO:

My prints are really good.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.